# Installing PyDrive on Mac

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to install PyDrive with a view to automating the back up of my work folder to google drive.

I'm trying to use pip to install PyDrive in the terminal and having no such luck.

When I run

```
pip install PyDrive
```

I get a syntax error, not sure if I'm being dumb but I can't see a syntax error.

Can't find any guidance about installing for Mac.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
pip install PyDrive
```

I'd expect PyDrive to start installing but just have a syntax error returned.

Comment: Hello Reece and welcome to SO. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to improve your questions so that other users may be able to help you. At first, I would suggest you should add the error message to your post

Answer (score 1):

You can try python installing the package for you and run it as a script via option -m.  I tried it on my mac and it works.

```
python -m pip install pydrive

Collecting pydrive
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/e0/0e64788e5dd58ce2d6934549676243dc69d982f198524be9b99e9c2a4fd5/PyDrive-1.3.1.tar.gz (987kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 993kB 8.8MB/s 
Collecting google-api-python-client>=1.2 (from pydrive)
```